# Using for loop to reverse Iterate over elements of a container/string without warnings in both 32-bit and 64-bit

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I just want to reverse-iterate over a container or over a string.

This sample code

```
for (int i = strlen (str) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    ...
}
```

will raise a warning on 64-bit compilation:

```
warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

On the other hand,

```
for (size_t i = strlen (str) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    ...
}
```

will cause an infinite loop, since size_t is unsigned.

I know I can use other techniques, **but I just want to use a simple for loop !**

How can I write a clean code for both 32-bit and 64-bit compilations?

Comment: Favorited - I did not know this was one of the differences for 32 and 64 bit

Comment: Call me pedantic, but there's no way to get "clean code" in C++, while using C strings. If you want to write clean C code, then don't pretend it is C++. If you want to write clean C++ code, then don't pretend it is C.

Comment: @jalf: you are right. It is just a simple example or iterating over something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change to:

```
for (size_t i = strlen (str); i--; )
{
    ...
}
```